# Thymeleaf th:replace using variable path

Tags: java, thymeleaf, openhtmltopdf

I'm trying to create a dynamic pdf using Thymeleaf and OpenHtmlToPdf. Each part of the pdf is in a different template.
These templates are included or not and the order can be modified.
I'm using a java enum that looks like this

```java
public enum FollowupPdfSummaryEnum {
   COVER("coverAnchor", "templates/firstPageInclude'.html'", "Couverture", FollowupBlocEnum.COVER_PAGE),
   SUMMARY("summaryAnchor", "templates/summaryInclude'.html'", "Sommaire"),
   SITUATION_PLAN("situationPlanAnchor", "templates/situationPlanInclude.html", "Plan de situation", FollowupBlocEnum.SITUATION_PLAN),
   BUILDING_VISUAL("buildingVisualAnchor", "templates/visualInclude.html", "Visuels", FollowupBlocEnum.BUILDING_VISUAL),
   HEALTH_BOOK("healthBookAnchor", "templates/healthBookBatInclude.html", "Carnet de santé", FollowupBlocEnum.HEALTH_BOOK),
   IDENTITY_CARD("identityCardAnchor", "templates/identityCardInclude.html", "Fiche d'identité", FollowupBlocEnum.IDENTITY_CARD),
   COUNTER_SITUATION_PLAN("counterSituationAnchor", "templates/counterSituationPlanInclude.html", "Plan des compteurs", FollowupBlocEnum.COUNTER_SITUATION_PLAN),
   DANGEROUS_MATERIAL("dangerousMaterialAnchor", "templates/dangerousMaterialInclude.html", "Diagnostic Matières Dangereuses", FollowupBlocEnum.DANGEROUS_MATERIAL_DIAGNOSIS),
   RECAP_WORK_TODO("workDoneAnchor", "templates/workTodoListInclude.html", "Récapitulatif des travaux à réaliser", FollowupBlocEnum.WORK_DONE_REPORT),
   VISIT_REPORT("visitReportAnchor", "templates/visitReportInclude.html", "Rapport de visite", FollowupBlocEnum.VISIT_REPORT),
   VISIT_REPORT_OCCUPATION("visitReportOccupationAnchor", "templates/occupationVisitReportInclude.html", "Rapport de visite : Occupations", FollowupBlocEnum.OCCUPATION_VISIT_REPORT),
   ANNEXE("annexeAnchor", "templates/annexeInclude.html", "Annexes");
   
   private final String anchor;
   private final String pagePath;
   private final String title;
   private final FollowupBlocEnum block;

   private FollowupPdfSummaryEnum(String anchor, String pagePath, String title, 
   FollowupBlocEnum block) {
      this.anchor = anchor;
      this.pagePath = pagePath;
      this.title = title;
      this.block = block;
   }
   private FollowupPdfSummaryEnum(String anchor, String pagePath, String title) {
      this.anchor = anchor;
      this.pagePath = pagePath;
      this.title = title;
      this.block = null;
   }
```

PagePath is the path i'm trying to use to add templates to my pdf. At first I was using something like this to add templates to my pdf

```html
<page-after id="p1"><div th:replace="templates/firstPageInclude.html"></div></page-after>
```

Then I replace it with something more dynamic

```html
<th:block th:each="summaryItem : *{summary}">
        <page-after id="${summaryItem.anchor}"><div th:replace= "${summaryItem.pagePath}"></div></page-after>
    </th:block>
```

Summary is a list of FollowupPdfSummaryEnum. Looks like it can't find the string path so it can't find the template.
If you have any idea, i'll take it thanks :)

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "summaryItem.pagePath"
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is possible I would asume it's done by telling thymeleaf to process the text within replace first using double `_` before and after the variable like so.

```html
<div th:replace= "__${summaryItem.pagePath}__">
```

Comment: it doesn't works, it seems to be more a OGNL exception problem due to my variable names, but i don't really understand

Comment: Should update post with complete class and stacktrace. Could be a lot of things such as missing getter for pagePath.